# What is the best way to install Oracle 11g R2 and SQL Developer on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, oracle-database

I read [this article suggesting use of Oracle's yum repository in conjunction with CentOS 6.x](http://www.tecmint.com/oracle-database-11g-release-2-installation-in-linux/).

I also read [this other article, which seems to suggest manually downloading zip files and taking many manual steps.](http://dbaora.com/install-oracle-11g-release-2-11-2-on-centos-linux-7/)

I am concerned about starting a process that will result in difficult to maintain elements in an incomplete installation, and then having relics left over after trying to replace an initial approach with other approaches.

If someone would be kind enough to guide me through a best practice approach from the start, I would be really grateful.

Note that I need SQL Developer in addition to the Oracle 11G R2 database server.

**Is there an official distro approach to installing/maintaining Oracle 11G R2 and SQL Developer?**  Like a CentOS managed approach or an RHEL managed approach?  Perhaps part of EPEL?

Comment: No, you won't find commercial software such as that in distro maintained repositories. In general, you should always use a `yum` repo unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: @jordanm The yum approach in my OP above is for CentOS 6.x.  How would I learn how to modify it for CentOS 7?

Comment: Change the "6" in the URLs to "7".

Answer (score 1):

There are Recommended Practices how to install Oracle 12c on RHEL:

- https://access.redhat.com/articles/725843
- https://access.redhat.com/articles/1357883
- https://access.redhat.com/articles/1282303

The last two links require a valid subscription, sorry.

Oracle also has documentation on this topic. However you will notice that most things have to be done by hand as there are no repositories for fetching the software.